# Bloqueio de LINK com HTACCESS

Tags: htaccess, aplicação-web, servidor

Preciso realizar um bloqueio de um link apenas dentro de um servidor, como seria com a utilização do HTACCESS? Caso haja alguma forma. Obrigado.

Comment: É um link interno da rede ou externo?

Comment: seria interno mesmo

Comment: Ao invés de htacess, pq não edita o hosts do Windows? Funciona muito bem:  127.0.0.1       seuendereço

Comment: Porque meu servidor é linux, não tenho outro tipo de permissao a nao ser com o htaccess Diego

Comment: Acho que entendi o que vc quer, veja a resposta que postei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de bloquear, creio que o ideal seria redirecionar. Se o link for acessado, direciona para uma outra página qualquer:

```html
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.456.789.000
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</ifModule>
```

[Fonte](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/miscelanea/htaccess-redirecionamento-automatico-sites-em-manutencao/)